# How to shim Leaflet + mapbox with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mapbox

I'm trying to shim leaflet and mapbox.

Below my shim:

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
    'leaflet': '/app/res/libs/leaflet/js/leaflet-1.6.0',
    'leaflet-draw': '/app/res/libs/leaflet/js/leaflet.draw-1.0.4',
    'mapbox': '/app/res/libs/leaflet/js/mapbox-1.6.2'
  },
  shim: {
    'leaflet': {
      exports: 'L'
    },
    'leaflet-draw': {
      deps: ['leaflet']
    },
    'mapbox': {
      deps: ['leaflet'],
    },        
  } // end Shim Configuration
});

define(["leaflet", "leaflet-draw", "mapbox"], function (L, dummy0, dummy1) {
  return L;
});
```

With the shim above my map works fine, but when I try to use something that is supposed be provided by Mapbox I get an error.

For example, the code below works fine:

```js
        // Add layers to the map
        L.control.layers({
            'Esri Satellite Map': L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
                attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
            }).addTo(map)
        }).addTo(map);
```

But if I try to use a tileLayer from Mapbox:

```js
        L.control.layers({
            'Mapbox Satellite Map': L.mapbox.tileLayer('bobbysud.map-l4i2m7nd', {
                detectRetina: true
            }).addTo(map),
            'Esri Satellite Map': L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
                attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
            })
        }).addTo(map);
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'tileLayer' of undefined`

How can I get Mapbox work ?